# Why can't I access this particular variable when referencing its outer environment?

Tags: javascript, this, lexical

I'm learning about lexical scope and execution contexts in JS and came across a question.

My understanding of the keyword `this` may be limited, but I see that it references all variables in any function's current execution context.

Consider this example:

```
function b(){
  console.log(this);
}
var myVar = 1;
b();
```

Here, I'll get a console log to myVar which will be assigned to the value 1.

Now for this example:

```
function a(){
   function b(){
     console.log(this);
   }
  var myVar = 2;
  b();
}
var myVar = 100;
a();
```

When function b is called, I see a reference to myVar, which is assigned to 100. Why isn't there a reference to myVar as assigned to 2?

Doesn't 'this' refer to the current function's lexical environment? In this case, function b is enclosed in function a and not the global environment.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding of `this` is completely wrong.

The value of `this` depends (usually) on how the function was called. (See [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for details).

If you are:

- in a browser
- your JS isn't running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which it should be)
- the function is called with no explicit context

… then `this` will be the `window` object.

---

Normally, when a variable is declared, it exists only in the scope in which it was declared. It is not a property of any object.

There is one exception:

When a variable is declared in the global scope (i.e. outside of any function or without `let` or `var` inside a function) then it also becomes a property of the `window` object.

---

The effect you are seeing is the combination of those two things.

`b();` has no context, so `this` is `window`. `var myVar = 100;` is outside of any function, so is a global and thus a property of `window`.

Comment: isn't b under function a's context? therefore function b as a reference to its outer environment in function a?

Comment: @user3882106 — No. As I said, context is determined by how a function is called, not where it is declared. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work . Don't confuse context and scope.